# How to detect exit signal triggered in c program - windows

Tags: c, windows

I wanted to call a bat file for cleaning temporary files of my program when the program triggered exit signal. I wanted to know how can I find out exit signal has been emitted by the program to the kernel? I am using VS studio and MSVC compiler. In simple words, I wanted to call a function when my program quite.

Comment: no any *exit signal* in windows. if you have process handle - you can wait on it.

Comment: The `exit(n)` function call will set the `ERRORLEVEL` that you can check in your .bat file.